# Geometry operations on latitude/longitude coordinates

Tags: sql-server, google-maps, geometry, geospatial, geography

My question is probably a duplicate, but all the answers I have seen so far do not satisfy me or still leaves me in doubt.
I have a web application that uses Google Maps API to draw and save shapes (circles and polygons) in a SQL Server DB with the geometry data type (where I save lat/long coordinates) and an SRID = 4326.

My objective is to later on, determine if a point is contained in the area of those circles/polygons thanks to SQL function `geometry::ST_Intersects()`.

I have been told so far that my method wouldn't work because I am using geometry instead of geography. But to my surprise...  after checking with a few tests, it works perfectly well with geometry and I am not able to understand why or how?
Could somebody explain to me why the geometry type works well with operations on lat/long whereas geography would be more suited?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I post as an answer because as comment is too long

geometry works well to the extent that your intersections are approximable to flat intersections.
the difference between geometry and geography consists in the fact that the former works by hypothesizing to work on plane surfaces the second on spherical surfaces. in the case in which the polygons in question are related to small areas in the order of a few thousand meters geometry works very well. the difference between measured distance by imagining that the points lie on a plane or that the points lie on the earth's sphere is so small as to be negligible. Unlike the question if the points are a few hundred kilometers in this case the distance measured in the plane or on the sphere is very different and proportionally is also the result of the intersection between these areas